# Simple keras autoencoder with MNIST sample data not working

Tags: r, keras, compression, mnist, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement a simple `keras autoencoder` in `R` using the MNIST sample dataset. I got my example from a blog but it doesn't work. I get almost a `0 %` accuracy.

The objective is to compress each `28 x 28` image (784 entries) into a vector of 32 entries:

Here's my code:

```
library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
x_train <- mnist$train$x

# reshape
x_train <- array_reshape(x_train, c(nrow(x_train), 784))
x_train <- x_train / 255

model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
 layer_dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(784)) %>% 
 layer_dense(units=784, activation='sigmoid')

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = 'adam',
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, x_train, 
  epochs = 15, batch_size = 128, 
  validation_split = 0.2
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `binary_crossentropy` as a loss function here. `categorical_crossentropy` is intended for multi-class classification problems (only one output is 1), `binary_crossentropy` is suitable for multi-label classification.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to run, but there is one more problem. I changed the input data from images to a random matrix that has positive and negative values. The decoded output only has positive values. Any idea why this is so? It seems like the autoenconder only wants and image (i.e. a matrix with positive values)

Comment: The output of a sigmoid function is always between 0 and 1.